# Kubernetes HA master set up

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I have made a HA Kubernetes cluster. FIrst I added a node and joined the other node as master role. 
I basically did the multi etcd set up. This worked fine for me. I did the fail over testing which also worked fine. Now the problem is once I am done working, I drained and deleted the other node and then I shut down the other machine( a VM on GCP). But then my kubectl commands dont work... Let me share the steps:

kubectl get node(when multi node is set up)

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
instance-1   Ready    <none>   17d   v1.15.1
instance-3   Ready    <none>   25m   v1.15.1
masternode   Ready    master   18d   v1.16.0
```

kubectl get node ( when I shut down my other node)

```
root@masternode:~# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server k8smaster:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Any clue?

Comment: FIrst check `kubelet` and `docker` services per each node.

Answer (score 2):

After reboot the server you need to do some step below:

1. sudo -i
2. swapoff -a
3. exit
4. strace -eopenat kubectl version